# Amazon SES with `aws configure sso`, getting an error saying "no credentials provided"

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, single-sign-on

I'm trying to use Amazon SES to send an email through `go` code.  I have used `aws configure sso` (everything works fine from the terminal).  This is what my go code looks like:

```
session, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region:                        aws.String("ap-southeast-2"),
    CredentialsChainVerboseErrors: &enable,
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal().Err(err).Msg("aws setup failed")
}
sesClient := ses.New(session)
```

When I try to send an email through something like `sesClient.SendEmail(input)` I get this errpr:

> NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated

I tried to set the default profile by using `export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=profile_name` hoping it would pick this up, but it still does not.

What I want it to do is to pick up the profile I have logged onto when using the sdK on my local box.  Is this possible?

Comment: Whenever I run `aws configure sso`, it offers to save the configuration to a named **profile**. Then, when I want to use those credentials with the AWS CLI, I need to specify that name in `--profile`. You will likely need to do something similar in your code to tell the `Session` which Profile to use. See: [session - Amazon Web Services - Go SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/) and search the page for `profile`.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK will automatically look for a credential in several possible locations (such as environment variables, default profile, IMDS if in EC2). I personally have difficulty in guessing which credentials it is using. To avoid this, always unset your environment variables. For profiles, you should be able to specify which one to use explicitly.

Example, when you use `aws configure sso`, save it as the `my_profile` profile. Then,

```
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region:      aws.String("us-west-2"),
    Credentials: credentials.NewSharedCredentials("", "my_profile"),
})
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this but no success, this actually is trying to open a file and i get the following error `SharedCredsLoad: failed to load shared credentials file
caused by: FailedRead: unable to open file, caused by: open /Users/username/.aws/credentials: no such file or directory`

Comment: That indicates something wrong with the `aws configure sso` step. It should create the `.aws/credentials` file. When it ran, it asks for which profile right? Or maybe try `aws configure sso --profile my_profile`? And did you need to login afterwards? `aws sso login --profile my_profile`

Comment: aws configure sso ran fine, and i could login fine to the profile afterwards.  with the `~.aws` folder i have the following structure

`cli (directory), config (file), sso (directory)`.  the `sso` folder contains the credentials and everthing.  there is now `credentials` file.  as far as i know that gets created when you use `aws configure`

Comment: Ok since the `credentials` file is there, before the profile inside expires, is the Go code working now?

Comment: sorry i meant "there is no `credentials`" file.  i mistyped it saying now.